# R language Function Factory: How to ensure safety?

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, namespaces

### The Problem

I would like to check whether a function factory in R is "safe". Here "safe" means the results of functions created by the factory depend only on their arguments, not on Global Variables.

### Description

This is an unsafe factory:

```
funfac_bad = function(){  
  newfun = function()
    return(foo)
  return(newfun)
}
```

The return value of newfun will depend on the value of foo at time of execution of newfun. It may even through an error if foo happens to be undefined.

Now - quite obviously - this factory can be made safe by binding foo to a value inside the factory

```
funfac_good = function(){
  foo = 4711
  newfun = function()
    return(foo)
  return(newfun)
}
```

I thought I could validate safety by checking for Global Variables in the factory. And indeed:

```
> codetools::findGlobals(funfac_bad) 
[1] "{"      "="      "foo"    "return"
> codetools::findGlobals(funfac_good)
[1] "{"      "="      "return"
```

But my actual use case is (much) more complicated. The functions of the factory depend on subfunctions and variables with hundreds of lines of code. Hence I sourced the definition and my factories in principle look like this:

```
funfac_my = function(){
  sys.source("file_foo.R", envir = environment())
  newfun = function()
    return(foo)
  return(newfun)
}
```

This is a safe factory if and only if code executed in "file_foo.R" binds the name "foo" to a value.
But (quite logically) `codetools::findGlobals` will always report "foo" as global variable.

### Question

How can I detect unsafe behaviour of such a function factory when definitions are sourced?

Comment: Obviously you can't, since `"file_foo.R"` may change between the time of your check and the time you call the function.  It can't possibly be safe.

Comment: Changes of the file are not an issue since I can check and immediately afterwards create the functions (or write protect the file or whatever). Once created the functions would then be safe since they are independent of the factory.

Comment: Why not build a function with the `file_foo.R` code in the body, and check that?  It only means changing about 5 lines in the file, to include the stuff before and after the `sys.source()` call.  If you know `file_foo.R` isn't going to change, why not put it in the function from the beginning?

Comment: Yes but in my case the sourced file(s) contain nested function/variable definitions with hundreds of lines of code. Simply dumping all this into the factory would make it likely incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just ensure you define a default value for `foo` locally before sourcing the external files? For example, suppose I have this file:

**foo.R**

```
foo <- "file foo"
```

and this file

**bar.R**

```
bar <- "bar"
```

If I write my function factory like this:

```r
funfac_my <- function(my_path) {
  foo <- "fun fac foo"
  if(!missing(my_path)) sys.source(my_path, envir = environment())
  function() foo
}
```

Then I get the following results:

```
foo <- "global foo"

funfac_my("foo.R")()
#> [1] "file foo"

funfac_my("bar.R")()
#> [1] "fun fac foo"

funfac_my()()
#> [1] "fun fac foo"
```

So the output will simply never depend on whether there is an object in the global environment called "foo", (unless the scripts you are running maliciously look for a global called "foo" to copy - but then that would presumably be what you wanted by sourcing that file anyway)

Note that you could set this up to throw an error instead of returning a default value by adding the line `if(foo == "fun fac foo") stop("object 'foo' not found")` just before the final line. This will therefore complain that `foo` is not found even though you have a wrong object called foo in the global workspace.

Comment: Yes, this might work. But defining defaults somewhat beats the purpose of "hiding" the definitions in the source files. In a way then one could argue Why have the "source" in the first place? And one cause of errors is forgetting/mistyping names. This risk cannot be mitigated by checking for the default values.

Answer (score 0):

You ask "How can I detect unsafe behaviour of such a function factory when definitions are sourced?"  I think the answer is that you can't, but changing it slightly would make it easy.

For example, suppose currently you have

```
foo <- undefined_value
```

as the only line in `"file_foo.R"`, and you want to be warned about the use of `undefined_value`.  My suggestion is that you don't do that.  Instead, put the whole definition of `funfac_my` into `"file_foo.R"`, wrapping that one line:

```
funfac_my = function(){
 
  foo <- undefined_value

  newfun = function()
    return(foo)
  return(newfun)
}
```

Now you can source that file, and have a function `funfac_my` to pass to `codetools::findGlobals`:

```r
codetools::findGlobals(funfac_my)
#> [1] "{"               "<-"              "="               "return"         
#> [5] "undefined_value"
```